# GTK: ScrolledWindow wants infinite space, how to limit it?

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I create a large TreeView within a GTK ScrolledWindow within a hpaned within a notebook within the toplevel window (and toplevel window has a limited default size).

When I create a ScrolledWindow with TreeView within, it gets allocated as much space as TreeView takes (which is greater than the screen size) and my toplevel window is resized to infinity. How do I limit ScrolledWindow's allocation or its Viewport size? What's the mechanism that determines its default size?

Comment: Please show some code, details can really matter with GTK+.

Comment: @unwind You're right. A minute please, I'll try to throw away everything irrelevant from the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question seems to be solved. The size requisition of ScrolledWindow depends on its `POLICY` (in the respective direction) and is equal to requisition of child widget (treeview) if POLICY_NEVER is set, see `gtkscrolledwindow.c`:

> scrolled window policy and size requisition handling:
>
> gtk size requisition works as follows:
>
> - a widget upon size-request reports the width and height that it finds to be best suited to isplay its contents, including children.
> - the width and/or height reported from a widget upon size requisition  may be overidden by the user by specifying a width and/or
>     height other than 0 through gtk_widget_set_usize().   a scrolled
>     window needs (for imlementing all three policy types) to request its
>     width and height based on two different rationales.
>
> 1)   the user wants the scrolled window to just fit into the space
>   that it gets allocated for a specifc dimension.
>
> 1.1) this does not apply if the user specified a concrete value value for that specific dimension by either specifying usize for the
>   scrolled window or for its child. 2)   the user wants the scrolled
>   window to take as much space up as is desired by the child for a
>   specifc dimension (i.e. POLICY_NEVER).
>
> also, kinda obvious:
>
> 3)   a user would certainly not have choosen a scrolled window as a
>   container for the child, if the resulting allocation takes up more
>   space than the child would have allocated without the scrolled window.
>
> conclusions:
>
> A) from 1) follows: the scrolled window shouldn't request more space
>   for a specifc dimension than is required at minimum.
>
> B) from 1.1) follows: the requisition may be overidden by usize of
>   the scrolled window (done automatically) or by usize of the child
>   (needs to be checked).
>
> C) from 2) follows: for POLICY_NEVER, the scrolled window simply
>   reports the child's dimension.
>
> D) from 3) follows: the scrolled window child's minimum width and
>   minimum height under A) at least correspond to the space taken up by
>   its scrollbars.

So, if you set POLICY_NEVER, the ScrolledWindow will request for itself all the place, required by its child (and possibly will bloat the screen, if its child is huge). Otherwise, it will request a minimum needed to draw scrollbars. Possibly more space will be allocated for it than was requested and it will get enlarged to a reasonable size within its parent.

Sometimes you might want to have 2 ScrolledWindows, sharing a single scrollbar. Unfortunately, it is impossible to just set POLICY_NEVER for one of them and have `scrolled_window1.set_adjustment() = scrolled_window2.get_adjustment()` due to the fact, that POLICIES influence the size requisition and scrolled_window1 will start to request unpredictable (possibly huge) amount of space.

Comment: but with POLICY_NEVER it doesnt scroll!

Comment: lol I know, but if u want gtk2 :) anyway this is fool ! i had to "manually " set the list content height using mycolumn.cell_get_size + some math; with policy automatic. crazy...